# How to create an iPhone application starting from an empty project and then adding one resource at a time?

Tags: xcode, ios

Instead of using the standard Xcode provided templates (view based, window based etc), is it possible to create a full fledged iPhone application by starting with an empty project ?

I mean can one first create an empty project first, and then one at a time, add the main.m file, then import the Frameworks, then add an xib, add UIApplication delegate class, make necessary connections etc...

Has anyone tried this? It would certainly help one understand the basic anatomy of an iPhone application.

Comment: With you on that: I do like the fact that on Android you can trivially build the entire thing from the command line file-by-file. I'm sure someone out there knows how to do it on the iPhone, but haven't come across any guides.

Comment: An empty project also contains no build configurations, which I think will be the hardest part of it all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. At least in Xcode 4.2, there is the "Empty" project template with no files, targets or build configurations.